# Prove that any $L^p$ function can be approximated with a sequence converging weakly but not strongly

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

**I want to prove that any $L^p$ function can be approximated with a sequence converging weakly but not strongly, for this:
Let $f \in L^p((0, 1))$, with $p \in [1, \infty)$.
Construct a sequence of continuous functions $(f_n)_{n∈N} \subset L^p((0, 1)) ∩ C^0((0, 1))$ such
that $f_n \rightarrow  f$ weakly in $L^p((0, 1))$ but not strongly.**

**Hints:**

- use  that any $L^p$ function can be approximated in the strong norm with a sequence of continuous functions
- use that a periodic perturbation converges weakly but not strongly to its average (
  Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma)

> **The Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma**: Let $p \in [1, \infty], \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be an open bounded set, and $Q \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be
> an open cube. Let $f \in L^p(Q; \mathbb{R}^M)$. Extend $f$ to the
> whole $\mathbb{R}^N$ in a Q-periodic way: $f(z) := f (y)$, with $z \in$
> $\mathbb{R}^M$  written as $z = y + q$ for some $y \in Q$ and $q \in$
> $\mathbb{Z}^N$. For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ define $f_n \in$
> $L^p(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^M)$ as $f_n(x) := f(nx)$.
>
> Then,
>
> (i) $f_n$ converges to $\bar f$ weakly in $ L^p(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^M)$, if
> $p \in [1, ∞)$;
>
> (ii) $f_n$ converges to $\bar f$ weakly∗ in
> $L^\infty(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^M)$, if $ p = ∞$
>
> with $\bar f$ the average of $f$ in $Q$

**My ideas:**

I guess the first hint refers to the use of mollifiers, so I can define $f_\varepsilon=f*\varphi_\varepsilon,$ in $\Omega_\varepsilon$ ( which should be well defined since $f \in L^p(\Omega)\subset L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$ ) where:

$\varphi_\varepsilon(x)=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\varphi(\frac{x}{\varepsilon}), x \in \mathbb{R}$

$\varphi$the standard mollifier: $\varphi(x)=ce^{\frac{1}{x^2-1}},$ if $|x|<1; 0 $ otherwise
(But I guess I have to change it a bit, because my domain is not centered at $0$, but am not very sure how. What about if I put $2x-1$ instead of $x$? like this:  $\varphi(x)=ce^{\frac{1}{(2x-1)^2-1}}, x\in(0,1); 0$ otherwise

$\Omega_\varepsilon=\{x\in\Omega: \text{dist} (x,\partial \Omega)> \epsilon \}=(\varepsilon,1- \varepsilon)$

$\varphi_\varepsilon \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}) \subset C^0((\mathbb{R}))$ and I think it would hold if I take $\Omega=(0,1) $ instead of $\mathbb{R}$?

Taking  $\varepsilon =1/n, $
$f_n(x):=f(nx)=\varphi_{1/n}(x)=n\varphi(nx), x \in \mathbb{R}$

**I am not sure  to which function I should apply  the lemma to get the  weak convergence in $L^p((0,1))$ to f, considering that it yields convergence to an average so for sure I can't apply it to f** . Besides  the lemma says nothing about the non strong convergence.  Could you clear up these ideas? How do I proceed from here?

Comment: I would just take a strongly approximating $f_n$ and add a term $r_n$ that converges weakly to $0$. An oscillating $r_n$ works.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, what would the expression for $r_n$ be? How would I prove $\tilde f_n + r_n$  doesn't converge strongly?( $\tilde f_n$ the strong approximant)

Comment: You should have seen the fundamental example $r_n(x)=\sin(nx)$ already.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Would the strong approximant be  the mollified f as I described?. Does your suggestion uses the lemma?

Comment: "use that any  function can be approximated in the strong norm with a sequence of continuous functions". This is a standard theorem. You should look for it in your textbook and understand it. In this case, it is more efficient than rediscovering it from scratch. There are indeed several possible proofs for it, via convolutions, via Lusin's theorem, etc...